# Boleto registrado - Banco do Brasil - Remessa automática

Tags: php, boleto

Tenho hoje geração de boletos bancários através de um sistema gratuito em PHP. No entanto, ele funciona somente com carteiras sem registro.

Agora, preciso implementar em meu sistema de vendas (que é próprio, não utiliza nenhum sistema pronto de loja virtual), a geração de boletos COM REGISTRO do Banco do Brasil, carteira de número 18. Ele exige geração de remessa de dados para o banco para registrar cada boleto que é emitido.

A dúvida é, como fazer para enviar o arquivo de remessa de forma automática, quando o boleto bancário for gerado, os dados do boleto sejam remetidos para o banco para que o boleto seja válido.

Comment: O banco libera alguma API de comunicação para enviar estes arquivos? A última vez que trabalhei com boletos isso não existia para nenhum banco dos quais eu implementei. Se não existe API de comunicação, não tem como fazer o envio ser automático. Lembro que quando eu trabalhei com boletos, existia um sistema em alguns bancos que ficava instalado no computador do cliente e "monitorava" uma pasta, sempre que surgia um arquivo remessa ele se encarregava de fazer o upload e depois baixar o retorno para uma pasta pré-definida. Isso era o máximo que conseguíamos fazer para automatizar o processo.

Comment: E para uso de comércio eletrônico? Como funcionaria? Pois boletos são gerados no final de semana, e se não for enviado o arquivo de remessa para o banco, o boleto ficara inexistente para pagamento enquanto não registrar no banco.

Comment: Olha, até onde eu sei não tem nenhum problema o boleto ser pago antes de ser registrado, nunca teve problemas. Mas acho que é muito mais interessante você ligar pro banco e tentar falar com eles sobre isso, eles irão te responder com mais propriedade (ok, nem tanto, mas se insistir bastante talvez encontre alguém que entenda). Falo não só sobre a questão de de pagar os boletos antes de registrar, mas também sobre a possibilidade de envio automático de arquivos remessa. Lembrando que cada banco tem uma forma diferente de trabalhar, então, cada um pode ter uma maneira diferente de lidar com isso

Comment: Então, o banco que preciso é o Banco do Brasil.. Já liguei diversas vezes para o suporte técnico e ninguém sabe informar como funciona, e como devo proceder para implementar isso. Estão obrigando a implantação do boleto registrado até novembro, mas não tem um suporte especializado para dar informações.

Comment: É, eu sei bem como é isso, mas, infelizmente, não tem muito mais o que eu possa te ajudar. Talvez a ideia de registrar os boletos sempre na segunda-feira seja uma boa, mas não tenho certeza disso. Até fiquei curioso pra saber como *e-commerces* com grande fluxo de boletos fazem isso, talvez eles tenham algum "plano" diferente com o banco. Seria interessante conversar com o/a gerente da conta e pedir uma instrução.

Comment: Jbueno, você comentou do aplicativo do banco que monitorava as pastas.. sabe me dizer que aplicativo é esse?

Comment: Não sei. Eu lembro que é um recurso da Caixa Econômica Federal. O problema é que eles terceirizam esse tipo de coisa, ou seja, pra cada região é uma empresa diferente que cuida disso. E eu não lembro o nome da terceirizada.

Comment: Jrossetto e @jbueno deixei uns comentários relacionados nesse post, talvez interesse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175724/api-cef-ou-ita%c3%9a?noredirect=1#comment362453_175724